# month over month growth in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, date-arithmetic

There are two tables: table_1 and table_2

sample data of table_1

```
| order_id | order_date | user_id | quantity |
----------------------------------------------
| IX502334 | 2020-01-01 | user102 |    50    |
```

sample data of table_2

```
| user_id |   city   | country |
-----------------------------------
| user102 |  London  | England |
```

I want to find MOM (Month over month) growth of orders from country "Australia"

Here's what I have done:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM order_date) AS month_number, COUNT(order_id) AS orders FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 ON table_1.user_id = table_2.user_id
WHERE country = 'Australia'
GROUP BY month_number
```

The above should give me month wise count of orders for Australia

Now for MOM order growth,

```
select month_number, SUM(orders) as current_orders,
lag(sum(orders), 1) over (order by month_number) as previous_month_orders,
            (100 * (sum(orders) - lag(sum(orders), 1) over (order by month_number)) / lag(sum(orders), 1) over 
            (order by month_number)) || '%' as growth
            from (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM order_date) AS month_number, COUNT(order_id) AS orders FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 ON table_1.user_id = table_2.user_id
WHERE country = 'Australia'
GROUP BY month_number) table_3
            group by 1
            order by 1;
```

Am I correct? I don't have the database to run the query and check the result for myself.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your query will work because you are not including the year when extracting the month.  So, data from the same month in different years is being combined.

Assuming you have data for each month, you can just use `LAG()`:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM order_date) AS yyyymm,
       COUNT(*) AS orders,
       LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(order_date)) AS prev_month_orders,
       ( (COUNT(*) - LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(order_date)) /
        LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(order_date)
       ) as month_diff
FROM table_1 JOIN
     table_2 
     ON table_1.user_id = table_2.user_id
WHERE country = 'Australia'
GROUP BY yyyymm;
```

Note that you do not need a subquery to combine window functions with aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will mix months that belong to different years. It also has unnecessary levels of nesting.

I would phrase this as:

```
select 
    date_format(t1.order_date, '%Y-%m-01') order_month,
    count(*) as current_orders,
    lag(count(*)) over(order by date_format(t1.order_date, '%Y-%m-01')) as previous_month_orders,
    (count(*) - lag(count(*)) over(order by date_format(t1.order_date, '%Y-%m-01')))
        / lag(count(*)) over(order by date_format(t1.order_date, '%Y-%m-01')) as growth
from table_1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.user_id = t1.user_id
where t2.country = 'Australia'
group by order_month
```

You also need to worry about the possibility of monthes without sales; if so, your query will wrongly compare the results against the previous month that has sales. You can work around this with a range frame:

```
select t.*, 
    (current_orders - previous_month_orders) / nullif(previous_month_orders, 0) as growth
from (
    select 
        date_format(t1.order_date, '%Y-%m-01') order_month,
        count(*) as current_orders,
        sum(count(*)) over(
            order by date_format(t1.order_date, '%Y-%m-01')
            range between interval 1 month preceding and interval 1 month preceding
        ) as previous_month_orders
    from table_1 t1
    inner join table2 t2 on t2.user_id = t1.user_id
    where t2.country = 'Australia'
    group by order_month
) t
```

The subquery is not strictly necessary - it just avoids repeating the lengthy window specification three times.